# SupplyParameterFromQuery not working until after an Entity Framework call

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the following in a page:

```
<a href="@($"/Event/Profile?id={Value.UnderlyingEvent!.Id}")">
                Find out more
</a>
```

When the user clicks it goes to the following page (`Task.Yield()` added as an experiment):

```
[Parameter]
[SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "id")]
public int? EventId { get; set; }

private EventPageViewModel? Data { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{

    try
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();

        if (!IsLoggedIn())
            return;
        Task.Yield();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl))
            ReturnUrl = GlobalConstants.UrlHomePage;

        await using (var dbContext = await NoTrackingDbFactory.CreateDbContextAsync())
        {
            var @event = await dbContext.Events
                .IncludeAll()
                .Include(e => e.Signups)!
                .ThenInclude(signup => signup.User)
                .Where(e => e.Id == EventId)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

At the point where it calls `dbContext.Events` `EventId` is null. When it returns from the call (having failed to find the desired data because `EventId` was null), `EventId` now has the passed in value.

What is going on here and how do I get the value for `EventId`?

**Update:**

The following does work:

```
var uri = new Uri(Navigation.Uri);
var q = uri.Query;
string paramId = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(q).Get("id");
```

**Update 2:**

I've just spent 1/2 hour trying to create a MRE. No luck :(

I also found that if I paste the url into the browser, it works. If I hit reload (same thing I guess), it works. But clicking the link to go there - null value at first.

**Update 3:**

Calling `await Task.Delay(1)` and it works (thank you @HH).

There are no other overridden methods in the page. So no SetParam...

The @page is:

```
@page "/Event/Profile"
```

**Update 4:**

Per the request from MrC below, here's the console output. My CloseEvent.razor file inherits from ExComponentBase.cs. Neither has a `SetParametersAsync()` method but I added them for the Console output.

Here it is:

```
ExComponentBase.SetParametersAsync() params = Data = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LouisHowe.web.PageModels.EventJob.EventItemPageModel], EventChanged = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback`1[LouisHowe.core.Models.Event], CanEditOwner = False, ChildContent = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment`1[LouisHowe.web.PageModels.EventJob.EventItemPageModel], AuthenticationStateTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationState], PopupMessageBox = LouisHowe.web.Shared.PopupMessageBox,
ExComponentBase.SetParametersAsync() params = ChildContent = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment, AuthenticationStateTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationState],
ColseEvent.SetParametersAsync - EventId =
CloseEvent.SetParametersAsync() params = ReturnUrl = , EventId = , AuthenticationStateTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationState], PopupMessageBox = LouisHowe.web.Shared.PopupMessageBox,
ExComponentBase.SetParametersAsync() params =
Entering CloseEvent.OnInitializedAsync() EventId=
Entering ExComponentBase.OnInitializedAsync()
Leaving ExComponentBase.OnInitializedAsync()
CloseEvent.OnInitializedAsync() after call base EventId=
CloseEvent.SetParametersAsync - EventId = 20026
CloseEvent SetParametersAsync() params = ReturnUrl = /Manager/Dashboard, EventId = 20026, AuthenticationStateTask = System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationState], PopupMessageBox = LouisHowe.web.Shared.PopupMessageBox,
ExComponentBase.SetParametersAsync() params =
```

**Update 5:**

Base classes

```
public class ExLayoutComponentBase : LayoutComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    protected ISessionData SessionData { get; set; } = default!;

    [Inject]
    protected IExUserManager UserManager { get; set; } = default!;

    [Inject]
    protected IBlobService BlobService { get; set; } = default!;

    [Inject]
    protected NavigationManager Navigation { get; set; } = default!;

    [Inject] 
    protected ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory { get; set; } = default!;
            
    [CascadingParameter]
    protected Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationStateTask { get; set; } = default!;

    /// <summary>
    /// Built from AuthenticationStateTask - the logged in Principal (user).
    /// </summary>
    protected ClaimsPrincipal Principal { get; set; } = ClaimsPrincipalExtensions.Anonymous;

    /// <summary>
    /// The logged in user. This is the user that is signed in. Set in Initialize() so
    /// treat as non-null after that.
    /// </summary>
    protected AppUser User { get; set; } = AppUser.CreateAnonymous();

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();

        // This will:
        // 1. Initialize Principal.
        // 2. Assign the logged in user to the User property.

        Principal = (await AuthenticationStateTask).User;

        var user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(Principal);

        // when they login, we don't know it. And there are other minor cases where we don't know
        // that these settings have change. And this is an incredibly lightweight call. So we always
        // call this
        if (SessionData.ShowAnything || !SessionData.DataInitialized)
            SessionData.Reset(user);

        if (user == null)
        {
            SessionData.AnonymousUser ??= AppUser.CreateAnonymous();
            User = SessionData.AnonymousUser;
        }
        else
            User = user;
    }

}

public class ExPageBase : ExComponentBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Set to true to display the loading indicator. This requires that the page has the &lt;DxLoadingPanel>
    /// in the page content with Visible="@IsLoading".
    /// </summary>
    protected bool IsLoading { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// If the user is not logged in, will NavigateTo() the login page and return false. In this case, stop
    /// initializing the page on and return.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>true if the user is logged in.</returns>
    protected virtual bool IsLoggedIn()
    {

        if (User.IsAnonymous)
        {
            Navigation.NavigateTo(GlobalConstants.UrlLogIn, true);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

CloseEvent.razor (just the top)

```
@page "/Manager/CloseEvent"
@attribute [Authorize]
@using LouisHowe.web.PageModels.EventJob
@using Rating = LouisHowe.web.Shared.ExRating
@implements IDisposable
@inherits ExPageBase

@if (@Model.EventModel != null)
{
    <h2>Please rate - @Model.EventModel.Subject</h2>
}

<EditForm EditContext="EditContext" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmitAsync" OnInvalidSubmit="HandleInvalidSubmitAsync" Context="editFormContext">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <CustomValidation @ref="_customValidation" />
    <DxFormLayout>
```

CloseEvent.razor.cs (just the top):

```
public partial class CloseEvent : ExPageBase
{
    [Inject]
    private ScopedLoggerFactory<CloseEvent> ScopedLoggerFactory { get; set; } = default!;

    [Parameter]
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "returnUrl")]
    public string? ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "id")]
    public string? EventId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Built from ScopedLoggerFactory
    /// </summary>
    private ScopedLogger<CloseEvent> Logger { get; set; } = default!;

    /// <summary>
    /// The event we are editing. Set in OnInitializedAsync() so treat as non-null after that.
    /// </summary>
    private Event _event = default!;

    /// <summary>
    /// The EditContext for the form.
    /// </summary>
    public EditContext EditContext { get; set; }

    private CloseEventPageModel Model { get; }

    private bool SubmitEnabled { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// true if a field has been edited and not saved. So the data is dirty.
    /// </summary>
    private bool HasUnsavedChanges { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to show signup effectiveness validation issues.
    /// </summary>
    private CustomValidation? _customValidation;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public CloseEvent()
    {
        Model = new CloseEventPageModel();
        EditContext = new EditContext(Model);
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        try
        {
            await base.OnInitializedAsync();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl))
                ReturnUrl = GlobalConstants.UrlHomePage;

            if (!IsLoggedIn())
                return;

            Logger = await ScopedLoggerFactory.GetLogger();

            if (!int.TryParse(EventId, out var id))
            {
                await PopupMessageBox.ShowThenRedirectAsync("Close Event",
                    $"Please enter a valid Id. {HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(EventId)} is not an integer.",
                    ReturnUrl!);
                return;
            }

            // get the event and the signups, populate the Model
            await LoadFromDatabase(id, User);

            EditContext.OnFieldChanged += OnFieldChanged;
            SubmitEnabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Data.TryAdd("Category", typeof(CloseEvent));
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This should not happen. Any code in SetParameters or something?  Create and post a [mre].

Comment: @ℍℍ I just tried (added an update) - no luck. Anything minimal works. And yet this page is very simple and... this should be set before `OnInitializedAsync` is called so simple or complex page - should be irrelevant. This is weird.

Comment: Try `Task.Delay(1)` instead of Yield(). Also, post the @page line. And answer about SetPArameters.

Comment: @HH That resolved it. But that leaves the question - why? And no other overides so no SetParam...

Comment: I don't see the "why"  either so I won't make it an answer. Neither Yield() nor Delay() should be required but Delay() is the stronger way to get the same situation as "_after_ the db call"

Comment: Anything else non-standard, such as the base-class ?

Comment: @HH Yep, it inherits from a class that inherits from a class that inherits from `ComponentBase`. But I did that in my MRE and that still worked. The lowest base class has a `OnInitializedAsync`, but no SetParam or any other overrides.

Comment: @ℍℍ I added Console output per Mrc's suggestion. Weird that it first sets all the `[Parameter]` items to null.

Comment: The next step is to make the MRE more and more like the real code, until it reproduces the problem.

Comment: Can you clarify your component names, hierarchy, and contents of SetPatamtersAsync. I have an idea what the problem might be.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis added. I tried creating a MRE like the above, but that worked (for me). TIA

Comment: I can't replicate it in a MRE.  See my updated answer for a request to log what is going on.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Thank you, I will. But it'll have to be next week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a NuGet update and... the problem went away.

I'm on the pre-release of .NET 8 and so it looks like this was a bug that they fixed.

Answer (score 1):

What you don't show is `ExComponentBase`.

Can you:

1. Temporarily install `Blazr.BaseComponents` for Nuget.
2. Set `ExComponentBase` to inherit from `DocumentedComponentBase` instead of `ComponentBase`.

```cs
public class ExComponentBase : Blazr.BaseComponents.ComponentBase.DocumentedComponentBase
{
\\..
}
```

3. Add the following to `CloseEvent` to read out the parameters passed in to the component.

```cs
    public async override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{parameter.Name} = {parameter.Value.ToString()}");
        }

        parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);

        await base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
    }
```

This should then output a log to the console session.

You should then get something like this:

```cs
===========================================
193c - Test => Component Initialized
193c - Test => Component Attached
EventId = 1
193c - Test => SetParametersAsync Started
193c - Test => OnInitialized sequence Started
193c - Test => OnInitialized sequence Completed
193c - Test => OnParametersSet Sequence Started
193c - Test => StateHasChanged Called
193c - Test => Render Queued
193c - Test => OnParametersSet Sequence Completed
193c - Test => SetParametersAsync Completed
193c - Test => Component Rendered
193c - Test => OnAfterRenderAsync Started
193c - Test => OnAfterRenderAsync Completed
```

Show me what you're getting.

Comment: Ok, posted above. Happening with another class so added the Console output there. You are right that something weird is going on, but I have no SetParam overrides anywhere in all this (aside from the ones I added per your suggestion).

Comment: And now it's working *%@#! I did a NuGet update this morning. I'm on .NET 8. My guess is this was a bug that is now fixed. THank you for all your help and Blazr.BaseComponents looks useful - lots more logging from inside.